# is there a version of react-svg-map for react 18.0.2?

Tags: reactjs

I need react-svg-map for react 18.

It looks like there's nothing later than react 16.0.0 for reaact-svg-map 2.2.0 available.

I haven't been able to find anything on the topic.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Try an updated alternative which is equally good.

react-simple-maps - This is keeping up with the updates.